# contentControl delete issue in word using office js

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins, officedev

I appreciated for contentControl but I am facing a issue when I deleting contentControl this is deleting contentControl only gives error when I was deleting contentControl when contentControl is inside another contentControl for example

`1st contentControl`

`2nd is inside 1st`

```
 `3rd is inside second`
```

now `second` is inside `first` and deleting successfully and `third` is inside `second` but when I am trying to delete `third` that was gives error
`generalException = "GeneralException`

[image: Error Image]

this is my code for deleting contentControl with its tag.

`

```
async function deleteContentControlByTag(tagToDelete) {
     try {
          await Word.run(async (context) => {
          const contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
          context.load(contentControls, 'items');

          await context.sync();

           // Find the content control with the specified tag
          const contentControl = contentControls.items.find(cc => cc.tag === tagToDelete);

            if (contentControl) {
              contentControl.delete();
               await context.sync();
              console.log('Content Control deleted.');
            } else {
               console.log('No content control found with the specified tag.');
             }
        });
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error:', error);
   }
 }

 // Call the function to delete the Content Control with the specified tag
const tagToDelete = 'f4022b4f-f104-4e13-a86c-1f0cc359fbb7';
deleteContentControlByTag(tagToDelete);
```

`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is just a copy of an issue the user raised on the repo for the Office JavaScript library reference documentation. He or she didn't even bother to delete the boilerplate for issues raised in that repo.

Comment: @RickKirkham , I posted this issue on repo. but anyone not responding on it that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: @RickKirkham since when is cross posting from another site a reason to close a question? The OP has stated they didn't get a reponse and moved to SO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Comment: @MЈǚйáĩď if you cross post, you should link to the other post/resource so we can follow for further details if needed.

Comment: @MЈǚйáĩď try to create a full reproducible example please --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Apparently, reasonable minds can differ as you'll see by googling on "Is cross posting to stack overflow and another site allowed?" I'm sympathetic with [Is it ok ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange), but you're free to disagree. The OP posted on the other site on a long holiday weekend and then posted here less than 24 hrs later. Again, you may disagree, but IMHO, the OP is unreasonable to assume that they weren't going to get answer on the other site.

Comment: @RickKirkham I hear ya, and I also note it is a poor quality question tbh..., I just know how hard it can be to become a positively contributing member of SO, wanted to "back the underdog" and hopefully Q can be improved.